# animate new tableviewcells with a pause

Tags: ios, swift, animation, tableview, cell

I am trying to display new tableview cells with a brief pause between each one appearing so the user can distinctly see new rows have been added to an exiting tableview. I have tried the code below with different animation times but it isn't working.

```
self.tableView.reloadData()

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 24.8, animations: {
        cell.contentView.alpha = 24.0
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why would you set the `alpha` to 24? It needs to be a value in the range 0.0 to 1.0. And the alpha is already set to 1.0 so animating it to 1.0 won't do anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3,
                           delay: 0.5,
                           options: .curveEaseInOut,
                           animations: {
                //Animation code.....
},
                           completion: nil)
```